# html-react-parser package's latest version(v1.5.0) is running into recursion

Tags: reactjs, html-parsing, html-react-parser

If I write an import statement for html-react-parser package (v1.5.0) in reactjs , it is running into recursion and producing the following error.
"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

If I remove the import statement , application is working fine.
For version v1.4.8 , it is working fine